# Como asigno datos a un array dentro de un objeto sin tener que asignar manualmente su posicion?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de asignar un valor a un array de un objeto, pero no se bien como hacerlo.

Les cuento:

Estoy trayendo datos mediante una subscripcion a un servicio del cual me retorna un objeto mcd con varios datos.

Recorro cada registro que trae mcd y se los asigno a detalleParte.

Hay dos datos que rescato desde ese servicio los cuales son una glosa y una fecha.

```
mcd.forEach(detalleParte=>{

    this.detalleCautelarParte = new MedidaCautelarDetalle();
    
    let glosa:string;
    let fecha:string;

    glosa = detalleParte.tipoMedidaCautelar.glosaTipoMedidaCautelar;
    fecha = detalleParte.fechaIniMedCautelar;
```

Despues necesito asignar cada uno de esos datos en otro arreglo (detalleMedidaCautelar) que se encuentra dentro de un objeto (medidaCautelarGrilla) que representa una grilla de datos.

Si se ve al final en el comentario //, la unica forma que puedo asignarle por ejemplo la fecha, es determinando a mano la posicion del elemento del array, en este caso posicion [0].
En la linea de arriba (q esta incorrecta), seria lo ideal para llevar a cabo pero lamentablemente no funciona de ese modo.

El problema es que como esa posicion es variable, necesito que automaticamente vaya colocando el dato fecha en la variable fechaCreacion para cada registro.

No se que propiedad se pueda usar ahi, me imagino que un forEach como arriba, pero, no se si sea realmente aplicable.

```
this.medidaCautelarGrilla = new MedidaCautelar();
this.medidaCautelarGrilla.idParte = relacionParte.id;

this.medidaCautelarGrilla.idFuncionarioCreacion = this.localStoreService.obtenerFuncionario().crrIdfuncionario;

this.medidaCautelarGrilla.detalleMedidaCautelar.tipoMedidaCautelar.glosaTipoMedidaCautelar = glosa;
    //this.medidaCautelarGrilla.detalleMedidaCautelar[0].fechaCreacion = fecha;
}
```

Como podria asignar las fechas y las glosas a cada elemento de ese arreglo que se encuentra en el objeto?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: this.medidaCautelarGrilla.detalleMedidaCautelar[XX].fechaCreacion = fecha; `podes usar findindex para reemplazar el xx, y encontrar el indice que buscas, en la pregunta falta info para poder darte un ejemplo valido y a mi parecer te estas enrroscando mucho.

Comment: podes mostrar un ejemplo de tu "this.medidaCautelarGrilla" para ver su estructura?